# Why does doFinally() get triggered early when using a scheduler?

Tags: project-reactor

When using a scheduler, doFinally() is executed before the whole Mono is completed:

```java
// Inside my component.
var inner = Mono.just("a")
        .doFinally(s -> System.out.println("Finally"));
// Component that uses my component.
inner
        .flatMap(a -> Mono.just(a).publishOn(Schedulers.single()))
        .doOnSuccess(a -> System.out.println("Success"))
        .subscribe();
```

produces

```
Finally
Success
```

Why is doFinally() executed before doOnSuccess()?

When not using the scheduler the order is as expected

```
Success
Finally
```

In my component, I want to ensure that some cleanup happens when the whole Mono has been completed. Who to achieve that?

Comment: `publishOn` forces the `doOnSuccess` to run on the `single` scheduler. What your resources are and why you need to clean up that way?

Comment: I write downloaded HTML content to disk to reduce the amount of used heap. I want to get rid of these temp files when the request is completely processed.

Comment: So you need the client component to cleanup. The inside chain does not know when the whole chain will be completed.

Comment: Yes, I could do that, but I don't want to spread that logic around the code. 

I thought that the whole construct is one chain because the signals make it to the end of the chain. Isn't that the case? How do I know where the boundaries are? IMO it is hard to understand that depending on the scheduler (immediate vs. single) the behavior is different.

Comment: `immediate` does not change the thread. I can not see the benefit of using `single` and `publishOn` at that point.

Comment: You are right, there is no point in that but just because it is a simplified example.
In the real code, the flatMap() is published on a parallel scheduler because of CPU-intensive computations.

Comment: Have a look at `Mono#usingWhen`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. That method solves the problem with multiple subscribers, but it won't solve the problem with the doFinally() being executed too early.

Comment: `Mono#usingWhen` takes an asyncCleanup parameter.

Comment: Yes, but when I wrap the inner Mono (the first two lines in the example) with usingWhen() (and return the resulting Mono to the outside) the async cleanup is still triggered before the outer Mono (that one published on the explicit scheduler) has finished processing. Thus it doesn't solve my problem. I want to define a callback at the inner Mono that gets triggered when all subscribers down the chain are completed (in the example the final subscribe() call).

Comment: `I want to define a callback at the inner Mono that gets triggered when all subscribers down the chain are completed` I don't think it is possible since you switch to a different thread.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that!